# UIImage displayed in cells with specified string value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

This piece gives strange results in my TableView. I want the `UIImage` displayed for the cells where the reprecented objects value for key "Marked" = "Yes".

What is the correct code for this?

```
if ([[[sortedObjects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Marked"] isEqual:@"Yes"])  
{
    cell.markedImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"markedItem.png"];
}
```

Comment: Is cell a custom UITableViewCell and is markedImageView a property?  What is the error you are seeing?

Comment: That's right. The image seems to populate cells where the value for key "Marked" is NOT "Yes" as well, pretty randomly through the TableView.

Comment: Is "Marked" a BOOL? if so you should compare it to YES not to the string @"YES".

Comment: No it's just a string with text "Yes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to clear the imageView image each time the cell is reused.

```
- (void)configCell:(MyCustomCell *)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath)indexPath
{
  cell.markedImageView.image = nil;

  // configure cell normally

  if ([[[sortedObjects objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"Marked"] isEqual:@"Yes"])  
  {
    cell.markedImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"markedItem.png"];
  }
}
```